# Is it possible to capture global keyboard events on macos with haskell?

Tags: macos, haskell

Is there an API for haskell on macos that lets me capture global keyboard events? All I found on the web is related to keyboard events reaching the current application (be it in the terminal, readline, gui).

I want to intercept capslock keydown and change it's meaning using haskell (because I love haskell). Just asking if anyone knows of a way.

Comment: Do you not know how to do this on macOS at all, or do you know how to do it in another language but not Haskell?

Comment: I know about the NSEvent API available from swift/objective-c/c++... there is also something related to IOKit around. I haven't looked into it yet. So yeah, I know where to look for other languages but for haskell I haven't found anything.